# Problem with Texlive 2016

Tags: errors, packages, texlive, installing

I was wondering how to add some `.sty` file that Texlive 2016 doesn't include, in my case, `points.sty`. I simply copy and paste to the path `C:\texlive\2016\texmf-dist\tex\latex`, however it seems to not work.

Comment: don't add files to the texmf-dist tree if they are not under control of the package manager. The simplest thing to do is just put it in the same folder as the document

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  You should put them in `\texmf-local\`.